# $watch not working for factory variables in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an below factory named SharedService

```
  angular.module('Fms').factory('SharedService', function() 
  {
    var userdetails=false;
    return userdetails;
  })
```

belew controllers shares this factory

```
angular.module('Fms').controller('mainCtrl',['$scope','SharedService',function($scope,SharedService)
 {
    $scope.userdetails=SharedService;
    $scope.$watch(SharedService, function(newValue, oldValue, scope) 
    {
        console.log(SharedService)
        if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) 
        {
            $scope.userdetails = SharedService;
        }
    });
 }]);


angular.module("Fms").controller('LoginCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','SharedService',function($scope,$http,$location,SharedService)
{
$scope.results ="";
$scope.name ="";
$scope.pass ="";
$scope.errormessage="";
$scope.login=function()
{
    $http(
    {   
        method: 'get',
        url: '/login',
        params : {username:$scope.name,password:$scope.pass},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    }).
    success(function(response) 
    {
        if(response=="success")
        {
            $scope.errormessage="";
            SharedService.userdetails=true;
            $location.path("/home")

        }
        else
        {
            $scope.errormessage="Enter valid Username & Password";
                SharedService.userdetails=false;


        }
    }).
    error(function(response) 
    {

    });
}
 }]);
```

Problem is i want to update the SharedService factories variable userdetails from LonginCtrl controller based on the response for authentication.

At the same time $scope.userdetails=SharedService; from mainCtrls needs to be updated using $watch. Buts its not working

Comment: Since your $scope.userDetails already point to SharedService object, it will automatically get updated. You do not need to watch.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write your factory like this

```
angular.module('Fms').factory('SharedService', function() {
    var _userdetails = false;
    return {
      changeUserDetails: function(details) { _userdetails = details },
      getUserDetails: function() { return _userdetails }    
    }
})
```

In mainCtrl you should then write

```
$scope.userdetails=SharedService.getUserDetails();
$scope.$watch(function(){ return SharedService.getUserDetails()}, function(newValue, oldValue) 
{
    if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) 
    {
        $scope.userdetails = SharedService.getUserDetails();
    }
});
```

and in loginCtrl

```
SharedService.changeUserDetails(true);
```